# TikZ Circle/Ellipse Around Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I'm making a multiple choice question and answer. How do I make an *appropriate* shape (probably an ellipse, oval, or rectangle in this case) around the correct answer without messing with the text alignment?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Two plus thirteen equals FIVE/NINETEEN/\tikz \node[draw,circle]{FIFTEEN}; /NINETY

\end{document}
```

[image: this doesn't look right...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `baseline` for a TikZ picture is the bottom of the picture, but you can reset that baseline in the options to the call to `\tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Two plus thirteen equals FIVE/NINETEEN/\tikz[baseline=(word.base)] \node[draw,circle] (word) {FIFTEEN}; /NINETY

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this will nevertheless interfere with the interline spacing if there is a following line:

[image]

Unless you've got a lot of white space around what you're going to circle, I don't thinking *circling* is going to be the right choice.  I would actually define a control sequence to handle this because then within the control sequence you can do a few things that AFAIK you can't do with `\tikz....;`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\circleanswer[1]{%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(word.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt]  (word) {#1};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[draw] at (word) {\phantom{#1}};
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

Two plus thirteen equals FIVE/NINETEEN/\circleanswer{FIFTEEN}/NINETY

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I suppose you might try something with an `overlay`, but in the above code, I basically prevent the bounding box from being enlarged over what was need for the `word` node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've started to use the code, but I don't really understand how it works. ATM, my main questions are: (1) What is the whole `baseline=(word.base)` part doing?, (2) What is a `pgfinterruptboundingbox`?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Regarding `baseline=(word.base)`.  A picture has a baseline that by default lies on the bottom of edge of the bounding box.  TikZ allows you to reset the baseline which is what this directive does.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Regarding `pgfinterruptboundingbox`.  The TikZ picture lies within a bounding box which determines its dimensions within the LaTeX document.  With each stroked path and creation of nodes, TikZ further updates the bounding box's dimensions.  `pgfinterruptboundingbox` tells TikZ not to update the bounding box dimensions and thus the picture can *bleed* out into the surrounding area.