# TikZ Circle/Ellipse Around Text, Part 2 - ExSheets Spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, exsheets

This is a follow up to [Part 1 TikZ Circle/Ellipse Around Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280517/tikz-circle-ellipse-around-text).

My new problem: Since combining the answer from the last thread with ExSheets, there extra spacing around the correct answer. Why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circleanswer[1]
{
 \PrintSolutionsTF
  {
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(word.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt]  (word) {#1};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[draw,color=red] at (word) {\phantom{#1}};
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {#1}
}

\begin{document}

Proper fractions live on the \circleanswer{LEFT}/RIGHT side of zero.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added several explicit spaces in the definition of the command. A new line is a space. Each new line in the command is, therefore, rendered as a space. The solution is simply not to insert the spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circleanswer[1]
{%
 \PrintSolutionsTF
  {%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(word.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt]  (word) {#1};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \node[draw,color=red] at (word) {\phantom{#1}};
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  {#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Proper fractions live on the \circleanswer{LEFT}/RIGHT side of zero.

\end{document}
```

[image: squished]